# Reconstruction 3D model from depth map

Tags: android, c++, opencv, 3d

I created a depth map from two stereo photos. Now I would like to create something like a 3D model. I know that it is not possible to get a "full 3D model". So, what is possible?

I know about Point Cloud but it gives me problems during linking of the program.

So, the questions are:

What are my options?
What are my options when it comes to displaying on Android?

Answer (score 1):

You have x and y coordinates of pixels, and you have depth for each pixel.
So you have all 3 coordinates to make 3D mesh.
Just use standard OpenGL methods to display it.

Comment: Pixel coordinates are not equal to point x and y. You'll need at least camera calibration matrix to do something meaningful

Comment: If depth map was computed using stereo pair, than cameras MUST be calibrated. So approach should work.